# AC MOSFET linear control

Tags: arduino, mosfet, batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging

I'm developing a circuit to control the charging, discharging and balancing of Li-po batteries.
Supply voltage will be ranging from 7 to 25 V, but not larger than the max. voltage of the charged battery. (If I connect a two-cell battery, say 3.5 V/cell, the supply voltage will be 8.4 V) and max current will be 3 A.

The critical part in this circuit is a minimal voltage drop. The current in such a circuit will flow in both directions, since batteries can be charged and discharged. That's why I decided to try modifying this schematic which is intended to switch AC:

[image]

My idea is to set one MOSFET in saturation mode, while the second one would be operating in its linear region. By doing that I'd have control over current, whether the the Li-po is charging or discharging.
I also suppose that I have to add some kind of current shunt to have feedback for the control unit.

How can I control the gates of the MOSFETs using an MCU and/or op-amp? How to control several independent circuits like this?

Comment: It's not conducting big amount of current, if we consider that this mosfet is fully on. Most current will go aside from the diode.

Comment: It'll be between 8-25V and current 0.1-2Amps

Comment: Nope, it's an standard ohmic load.

Comment: You are not following the necessary steps to start any design with adequate specs.  If you want a full wave rectifier with PWM then you need to define the load and supply voltage. May I suggest you read up on Half bridges and full bridges then ask a better question. You won’t find much help otherwise.

Comment: Okay, maybe I can explain this better in the other way. This circuit is intended to use in a Lithium-Polymer battery balancing circuit. Because I do not know whether I'll be charging or discharging those LiPo I do want to have a ability to control them both ways. The mosfets here act like a voltage-controlled curret source. This board will be suitable for batteries ranging from 8 to 25V, but in the same time, they cant be charged at more than 2-3Amps. These are the specs of the circuit. The whole rest eg. Microcontroler etc. is waiting to be designed. Hope this will clear things out:)

Comment: this is a whole different problem than the sine wave current . You need current sensing in the string  and voltage sensing for each node. Then a level shifter to raise Vgs  to achieve RdsOn spec yet limit it to not exceed rating.  Cell balancer are limited to power dissipation when bypassing 2A at 4.2V or 8W so this often can only be done when in CV mode when current reduces to much lower than 2A or have large heat conductors with force air cooling. Batteries must be balanced within tight tolerances and this extends the life of balance and usually not design to use unbalanced capacities or ESR

Comment: I suggest you understand how battery balancers work and their limitations before attempting this.

Comment: So how do battery chargers operate in CC mode?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

Is there really any point in doing this while operating in the linear region? From your question I'm guessing you want to control something like a DC motor, hence my answer will be directed at that.

A more appropriate way to control a DC motor, specially if you are using an arduino (which I assume you are since you used the arduino tag), is to simply use a full H bridge driven by PWM signals. A popular IC for small DC motors is the L293D - which is basically just 4 half-bridges.

Since you want bidirectional control, you can simply use a H bridge with PWM control. There exists unipolar PWM and bipolar PWM control. As an example, I will be explaining bipolar control since it's easier to understand: you apply PWM control to your entire H bridge, such that logic High in one arm turns one transistor on and the other off, and you make sure that the opposite happens in the other arm, like so:

[image: Bipolar]

With a 50% duty cycle, your motor turns slightly to one side, and then slightly to another. Do this fast enough and it doesn't even move. From 0%-50% it turns in one direction, while from 50%-100% it turns in the other.

Ok, but what if you actually want a sinusoidal output waveform and you are not controlling a DC motor? In that case you have a few different options. One of them is to use a DAC to generate your sine waveform, and then buffer that signal using an opamp in a voltage buffer/unit-gain configuration. This will be enough to power very light loads. A better option is to just simply use a [buck converter topology](https://www.electrical4u.com/buck-converter-step-down-chopper/), where you just switch a MOSFET using a PWM modulated sine wave, and let an LC filter take of eliminating the high-frequency harmonics for you. You might also want to add a series capacitor to the output to obtain a truly AC waveform.